# how can I make a fixed header and Mobile Menu in wordpress mobile theme

Tags: mobile, menu, header, fixed

I would like to making  a fixed header and Mobile Menu in wordpress mobile theme, such as the following example. how to make it?? thx

and by the way, I like this menu, what is this menu call? thx

http://themeforest.net/item/jackdaw-wordpress-mobile-theme/10563037

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a quick, acceptable and straight forward approach to a responsive header, you can make use of various libraies such as twitter-bootstrap.

By using such a library, you will not need to worry about most of the responsive coding behind the scenes.

However, if you would like a more custom approach to responsive design. You would want to look into making use of CSS media-queries(Base layout on various device parameters such as width, height and so on) and responsive best practices(Such as not being over using explicit sizing in your CSS)

Comment: thx, and you mean such header and menu need using twitter-bootstrap?? any simple way ??

Comment: Well bootstrap is a very simple framework to use, and makes designing responsive websites very fast and easy.